# Is $y=|x|$ a differential manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

In the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^2$, the function of absolute values $y=|x|$ determines a $1$-dimentional topological manifold $M$. Define the natural projection map
$$p:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R,$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto x,$$
let $f:=p|_M$ be the restriction of $p$ on $M$, then $M$ can be covered by two charts $U,V$, where $U=f^{-1}(-1,+\infty)$ and $V=f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$, the transition map between $U$ and $V$ is the identity map, which is clearly a smooth function, so according to the definition of differential (or smooth) manifolds (see for example [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#cite_ref-1%22) ), can we get the conclusion:
the function image of $y=|x|$ is a differential manifold?

Comment: You can use a single chart, for that matter. So, yes, you have a smooth structure on $M$, but with that structure it is not an embedded (smooth) submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, so, can we say $M$ as a subest of $\mathbb R^2$ is not a differential manifold, but $M$ can be given a smooth structure?

Comment: @Tom: You can say that it is not a **differentiable submanifold** of $R^2$ but, as a topological space,  admits a smooth structure, i.e. is homeomorphic to a smooth manifold.

Comment: If you're comfortable with groups, this is kind of like noticing that $\{0,1\}$ can be made into a group, i.e. $\mathbb Z_2$, but it is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$, even though it is a subset.

Comment: Thanks@MoisheKohan@JonathanZ supports MonicaC, your comments are really helpful.